# Parse address out of string that includes html <BR>'s in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an address thats in string that looks like this:

```
"1234 Something Street<br>Chicago, IL 34571<br>"
```

I'm having difficulty separating it out into the variables:

```
var street = ...;
var city = ...;
var state = ...;
var zip = ...;
```

Whats is a good way to do this in javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var sourceString = "1234 Something Street<br>Chicago, IL 34571<br>"
var arr    = sourceString.split("<br>")
var street = arr[0];
var arr2   = arr[1].split(" ");
var city   = arr2[0].substr(0, arr2[0].length - 1); // Strip the ","
var state  = arr2[1];
var zip    = arr2[2];
```

Comment: Are you sure those variables will contain what they state?

Comment: sorry.. overlooked the last line ;) now i guess it's correct.

Answer (score 4):

```
var matches = address.match(/^(.+?)<br>([\w ]+),\s?(\w{2})\s+(\d{5})<br>$/);;

var street = matches[1],
    city = matches[2],
    state = matches[3],
    zip = matches[4];
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/emW88/).

This new updated one will match *Salt Lake City*.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it multiple ways.

1234 Something Street
Chicago, IL 34571

first split it by **br**

```
arro[0]="1234 Something Street"
```

and the break by space...

keep doig this...until you get all values

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "1234 Something Street<br>Chicago, IL 34571<br>";
res = str.replace(/,\s/ , "<br>").split("<br>");
street = res[0];
city = res[1];
state  = res[2].split(' ')[0];
zip    = res[2].split(' ')[1];
```